# Is it possible in GSAP to prevent the execution of 'onComplete' if the animation didn't reach its endpoint?

Tags: javascript, animation, callback, gsap, cancellation

Is there a way to **prevent** the execution of `onComplete` if the animation was

- overridden / interrupted or
- never occured in the first place (because it was realized via `to()` and the value was already met)?

I assume `onInterrupt` could be used for that? If so, how?

---

UPDATE:

Here is a jsfiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/2f1jbwra/2/

---

jsfiddle with `kill()`: https://jsfiddle.net/2f1jbwra/4/
jsfiddle with `overwrite: "auto"`: https://jsfiddle.net/2f1jbwra/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interrupted tweens (and timelines) don't call their `onComplete` callback because they have been stopped. So just make sure your tweens are killing off the ones that they should by using `overwrite: 'auto'` or `overwrite: true`.

If you aren't actually interrupting the tween, you can remove the `onComplete` callback by using [`.addEventListener()`](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/Tween/eventCallback()) with `null` as the second parameter.

If you are interrupting the tween and you need to hook into that event, you can use the `onInterrupt` callback but that wouldn't help you in this case.

It's also worth noting that no events (including `onComplete`) will fire if the tween never started in the first place. With that being said, tweens where the start and end values are the same (like the situation that you describe in the question) are still ran like normal. It's just that you can't see any changes because none happen visually.

FYI you're more likely to get even quicker answers and additional commentary/helpful info and approaches if you ask GSAP specific questions like this [in the GSAP forums](https://greensock.com/forums/forum/11-gsap/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will post future GSAP questions there.

Comment: I've tested your approach, but I seem to do something wrong as `onComplete` is still being executed? In addition, I've added a jsfiddle example to the question.

Comment: k, I assume I have to store the tween object in a variable and invoke `kill()` before triggering the new animation.

Comment: `kill()` is not necessary if `overwrite: "auto"` is set in the vars. I misread the documentation and thought `"auto"` is the default value (but its actually `false`). Sorry for the spam.

Comment: After some thought, I do have a question about the `this` context of your answer. In the demo `this` refers to the global object. Would I also use the global object if it is used in a class, for example? Which object does hold the EventListener?

Comment: I was also wondering if I'm right in the assumption, that when there are two simultaniously running animations, overwritting the EventListener will result in clearing both onComplete callbacks?

Comment: Good catch. Interrupted tweens don't continue so the `onComplete` is never reached anyway. So you don't actually need `onInterrupt`. Events are called on a per tween (or timeline, depending on what the event is on) basis. I updated the answer.